# ODE non separation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics

I tried to solve this ODE question using integrating factor but it did not work.

$$(x-3y-5)dy+(5-3x-y)dx = 0$$

Is there any special theorem to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\:x=X+a\:$ and $\:y=Y+b\:$ so that the constant terms of the ODE will disapear. Bringing them into the ODE and simplifying lead to $\:a=2\:$ and $\:b=-1\:$
$$(X-3Y)dY+(-3X-Y)dX=0$$
This is an homogeneous ODE. Let $\:Y=Xf(X)\:$. The resulting ODE with unknown $\:f(X)\:$ will be a separable ODE.

Comment: Thank you very much!   how can we decide a=2 and b=-1 ? means anytime can we eliminate constants ?

Comment: $$(X+a-3(Y+b)-5)dY+(5-3(X+a)-Y-b)dX=0$$ Hense solve $a-3b-5=0$ and $5-3a-b=0$